# How to generate the build.gradle file for my existing Kotlin project in intelli J IDE

Tags: gradle, jackson, kotlin

I have create one Kotlin project. I wish to use [jackson-module-kotlin](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin#status)in my project. But they have mentioned to use gradle to add the jackson module. `compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.+"`
  But gradle files are yet to be added. So far I compiple and  built the project in IDE itself.

How to generate the gradle script for my existing project? so that, I can include the script to add the jackson dependency. Or is there any other way to use jackson in Kotlin project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a library that is published to the Maven Central repository as a dependency to your existing project built by IntelliJ IDEA, without converting it to Gradle:

*Project Structure* → *Modules* → Choose your module, e.g. `app_main` → *Dependencies* → *(+) Add* → *Library* → *New library* → *From Maven*

Then enter the Maven coordinates of the library (you should use a concrete version instead of a pattern, e.g. `2.9.4.1` and not `2.9.+`):

[image]

<sup>Check *Sources* as well if you want to navigate to the sources of the library.</sup>

Then choose the option to add it as a module library and confirm your choice.

Comment: Thanks @hotkey. How do I export this build script? So that I can share the project to anyone with the decencies ?

Comment: @esu, probably this is the answer: https://dzone.com/articles/sharing-intellij-idea-project

Comment: Thanks for sharing the resource.